# Reading integer values from a file

Tags: python, file

I've been trying to develop a program that will take a list of unique words and a list of their indexes from a file to create the original text but I can't get the integers converted back from str.

```
file=open("compressed_file_words.txt", "r")
listofwords = file.read()
file=open("compressed_file_word_positions.txt", "r")
positions = file.read()

for i in positions:
    reconstructed_text = reconstructed_text + listofwords[i] + " "
```

this fails with following error
TypeError: string indices must be integers

How do I get the str converted back to int? I have tried various methods but none seem to work

Comment: Your `i` variable is not an integer. You have to index `listofwords` with an integer.

Comment: With this `listofwords[i]` are you expecting to get a line from the file it was read from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(0, len(positions)):
    reconstructed_text = reconstructed_text + listofwords[i] + " "
```

Your problem is that `positions` is actually not an integer, and therefore `i` won't be an integer. `for` will literally iterate through every element of `position` and name that element `i` for the purposes of the `for` block. Since your block assumes an integer but is getting a string (a line from the file), you need to make your iterator an integer tied to the length of `positions`.

Note that you are probably misusing `read` and are actually looking for `readlines`.